# A question about zeroes in Fp

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I' m thinking a question.
Is it true the following proposition:
Fixed a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, there exists always a prime $p$ such that $ f(x)$ splits completely in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ ?

Comment: Check out the Chebotarev Density Theorem, and report back on your findings.

Comment: I find an article by Lenstra about the frobenius theorem and the relation between the automorphism in the Galois group and the "splitting type" of the polynomial mod p. The proposition is true because there is always the identity element. But is there a more direct approach to solve the question?